# ng serve memory increases with every hot reload

Tags: angular

Angular app started to crash for me after doing a bunch of reloads. A simple way to reproduce this it to start saving when for example in app component. After each refresh the ng serve process uses more memory and eventually ng serve crashes with out of memory error. Does anyone else get this issue and know how to fix it? In my opinion the memory usage should always remain the same if I am just saving the app without adding any new changes.

Comment: do you forget to unsubscribe from observables? This might cause memory leaks.

Comment: No all my subscriptions are handled.

Comment: ngOnDestroy is fired but the subscsriptions tied to async pipes seem to double up.